# Good way to fix a notched railing post?

Tags: deck, post, railing

My front porch has a corner railing post that is notched on two sides. The top is 4x4, but only about 1.5"x1.5" goes below deck and it's fastened to the rim joists there. It is quite wobbly, and not safe, and I'd like to fix it properly. Is there a way to do this relatively simply?

Comment: On the corner your top rail usually provides the strength. I am surprised they only went 1.5 below. I usually go to the bottom of the rim joist so there is room to put 2 bolts through. Without a photo my only guess is to replace the post and extend to the bottom of the rim joist. Make sure to anchor the top rail securely to the post for the most strength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer is to replace the post. But if you need a quick fix, perhaps a couple of braces would work. I think that a wood post anchor might work too, if you can slip it over or under the post (maybe it's too late for that).

[image]

[image]